# Mp3 player that lets you go back 5 seconds with the left arrow

Tags: audio, mp3

I'm looking for a mp3 player software that lets you go back say 5 seconds of the audio clip by pressing the left arrow key.

I'm using this as a means to memorize, and I used to use winamp on the PC and was wondering what choices I have on a Mac.

Answer (score 9):

As always [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html) will do that for you. The key combination:

<kbd>⌘</kbd> +<kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

from within VLC will skip forward 5 seconds. Left arrow for backwards.

You can also change the key combination, as well as skip, 10 or more seconds depending on the combination you choose from the menu, `VLC>Prefernces>Hotkeys`:
[image]

Comment: VLC is always a good bro. Never letting you down !

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler : those French they know how to code.

Comment: Funny that I came here looking for an alternative to VLC because it is freezing on my machine very frequently when I do this (I have a very new Mac, so it's hardly lack of resources)

Answer (score 7):

iTunes is highly scriptable.

You could write a one line AppleScript and then assign it to the the key combination of your choice.

```
-- iTunes Back 5
tell application "iTunes" to set player position to (player position - 5)
```

[Source](http://www.sixhat.net/applescript-how-to-skip-30rewind-10-seconds-in-itunes.html)

Answer (score 3):

To do what you want I would suggest following :

- Create an automator service
- Add a `run AppleScript` action
- Select  `service receives no input`
- Copy the following code in the AppleScript action : `tell application "iTunes" to set player position to (player position - 5)`
- Save you service
- Go to the `System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard shortcut`
- Add your a shortcut to your newly created service.
- Enjoy your new shortcut !